# Не запускается exe-файл

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Как создать нормальный exe-файл написанной в Qt Creator программы? Если просто взять exe-файл из папки `build-mdi--Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug` и попытаться запустить его на другом компьютере, то он будет просить DLL библиотеки. Однако если их положить рядом с exe-файл, то выдастся другая ошибка:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library.
>   This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Как сделать так, чтобы программу можно было нормально запустить через exe-файл на другом компьютере? И еще: будет ли программа корректно работать в 64-разрядной системе, если разрабатывалась в 32-разрядной?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, собирайте проект как релиз (release), т.к. отладочная версия (debug) в общем случае не предназначена для распространения после сборки на иных машинах. Да и динамические библиотеки, которые придётся копировать совместно с exe-файлом, в этом случае должны иметь суффикс "d" в своём наименовании.

Что касаемо релиза, то состав Qt-библиотек для деплоя зависит от используемых модулей. Очевидно, что если проект подключает в pro-файле, например, `QtCore`, `QtGui` и `QtWidgets`, то соответствующие библиотеки должны быть положены в ту же папку, где находится сам exe-файл.

Также, в случае с компилятором mingw (для msvc имеются отличия) не следует забывать копировать в папку с exe-файлом следующие библиотеки (они нужны всегда, в наименовании версия может отличаться в зависимости от версии Qt):

- `icuuc53.dll`
- `icudt53.dll`
- `icuin53.dll`
- `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`
- `libstdc++-6.dll`
- `libwinpthread-1.dll`

Также обязательным является наличие одной из библиотек из состава Qt-дистрибутива: `plugins/platforms`. В общем случае можно распространять `qwindows.dll`.

Если к проекту подключен хотя бы один из сетевых модулей, например, `QtNetwork` и/или `QtWebKit`, то потребуется в папку с exe-файлом, помимо одноимённых Qt-библиотек, положить ещё и библиотеки SSL (они находятся в `Папка_с_Qt_дистрибутивом\Tools\mingw\opt\bin`):

- `libeay32.dll`
- `ssleay32.dll`

Если к проекту подключен `QtSql`, то потребуется одна или несколько библиотек, использующих соответствующие СУБД из состава: `plugins/sqldrivers`.

Аналогична ситуация для `QtMultimedia` и прочих модулей.

Следует подчеркнуть, что плагины нужно копировать в папку с exe-файлом с сохранением исходной структуры каталогов за исключением того, что сама папка `plugins` создаваться рядом с exe-файлом не должна. В общем случае, структура файлов может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Project\
Project\translations\my_program_ru.qm
Project\sqldrivers\qsqlite.dll
Project\platforms\qwindows.dll
Project\Qt5Sql.dll
Project\Qt5Widgets.dll
Project\Qt5Xml.dll
Project\Qt5Core.dll
Project\Qt5Gui.dll
Project\Qt5Network.dll
Project\icuuc53.dll
Project\icudt53.dll
Project\icuin53.dll
Project\libstdc++-6.dll
Project\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
Project\libwinpthread-1.dll
Project\libeay32.dll
Project\ssleay32.dll
Project\my_program.exe
```

Проект, собранный посредством mingw на 32-х битной системе, будет работать и на 64-х битной. Могут быть нюансы, но это уже будет зависеть непосредственно от того, что реализуется в самом проекте.

Comment: Вроде бы ошибку теперь не выдает и запускается на х32 машине, а вот на х64 компе снова выдает это

Comment: @HorusWarmaster, попробуйте поставить Redistributable Package, как это предложил Cerbo, только берите установщик из комплекта самого Qt. Он лежит в папке `vcredist`. Не обращайте внимания, что он для x86, всё равно устанавливайте на 64-х битной машине. Затем попробуйте запустить свою программу снова.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы победить ошибку нужно устанавливать на целевой машине [C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784) причем той версии которая использовалась при сборке.